# What is the best way to migrate a project from php 5.6 to php 7.0?

Tags: php, migration

I'd like one solution to easily migrate my entire project made in php 5.6 to php 7.0. 
I've tried rector, but i'm having a lot of trouble.
Is there a better way to do it?
Thanks.

Comment: the best way is manual way

Comment: really? its a huge project =/

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.php is a good start. If you are using the old `mysql_*` functions then you are going to have to convert them all to `mysqli_*`.

Comment: What sort of troubles are you having with it? You may get a better response if you can state more specific issues. What kind of tests does your project have currently?

Comment: What kind of issues are you encountering with [Rector](https://getrector.org/) that aren't worth addressing?

Comment: It's a huge project, and rector says that i have a lot of duplicated classes. It will need a full refactor to avoid all the duplicated classes

Comment: @lvr7 Create a new issue, there might be a way: https://github.com/rectorphp/rector/issues